# Detecting of flat landscape / portrait orientation

Tags: swift

Is there way to detect if it is flat **and** landscape or flat **and** portrait orientation of device ?

I am asking about that becouse I have `UICollectionView` in my `UIViewController` and in Portrait mode cells are placed in one row, in line. In Landscape they are in only column - they swaped from horizontal to vertical. I have update of collection data for every 60 seconds. After this time have to call `reloadData()` to actualize the data and If I will leave device *inFlat orientation, layout will get destroyed, cuz of `sizeForItemAt`. None of conditions would be perfect.

```
let isPortrait = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait
if !isPortrait {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: collectionView.bounds.height / 4)
} else {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width / 4, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
}
```

There is no way to place it like this:

```
let isFlat = UIDevice.currentorientation.isFlat
if isFlat && isPortrait {
//
}
```

It can't be in same time `isPortrait` and `isFlat`.

Is there any work around this ?

Comment: Your code works fine with me. Is anything wrong here?

Comment: Sure it does, but as I've mentioned not in the situation when our device stays in flat portrait / flat landscape position and u will call `reloadData()`. The first `if` as you can see is !isPortrait = landscape, but when we leave our device on the desc and landscape so it will go after 60 second update to the flat instantly after we leave it on the desc ? It will call `else` statement and the result will be terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, to resolve it, you should save last size of item. When our device stays in flat, `sizeForItemAt` will return last size of item.

```
var currentSize : CGSize?

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  // In viewDidLoad, need to set default value for currentSize. Make sure in case
  // your app start at flat orientation, you collectionView still has a size
  currentSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: collectionView.bounds.height / 4);
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
  if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
    currentSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: collectionView.bounds.height / 4)
  } else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
    currentSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width / 4, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
  }
  return currentSize;
}
```

Only update value of `currentSize` when your device stays in portrait or landscape mode. If not, use current size of item.

Comment: Yeah, it's one solution which I was thinking about, but it's a bit messy, I've disabled those orientation from this `UIViewController`. Thank you for your time.